# function with options - should I use $.extend() to make code less verbose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, oop, extend

I'm building a status indicator like this:

```
G = { status : function(type, msg) {
    var opts = {
        'plain': ['#ccc', '#000'],
            'alert': ['#900', '#fff']
    }
    var $el = $('<div id="status"></div>')
        .css({
        'background': opts[type][0],
            'color': opts[type][1]
    })
        .html(msg)
        .appendTo('body');
    return $el;
}}
```

I call it like this:

```
G.status('plain','hello'); //makes a black text on grey background message
G.status('alert','ouch'); //makes a white text on red background message
```

**Question:**
Instead of CSS i might have more complex parameters, like an object of various options, some if which might be optional. is there a more elegant way of doing this? I have the feeling that i'm not really using javascript and jquery to it's best potential and making the code too complex.

Come to think of it, I guess this might have been asked elsewhere but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: I'm not trying to get this particular snippet reviewed. I'm trying to understand how to better structure functions with optional parameters.

Comment: I think $.extend is perfect for the situation you describe where you have a number of optional parameters you want to pass into the constructor. It might be worth updating your example so it's closer to   what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use classes. One advantage would be that you could add any number of status types without having to update the function which creates them. Just add the style to your CSS and you're on.

```
// type corresponds to a class in my CSS
function status(type, msg) {
    var $el = $('<div id="status"></div>')
        .addClass(type)
        .html(msg)
        .appendTo('body');
    return $el;
}

status('plain', 'hello');
```

CSS:

```
.plain {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: `…without having to edit your JavaScript`. The call must still be modified, and the CSS too. But the idea is good.

Comment: Fair point. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess that happens when I try to simplify my code example for clarity's sake. I'm actually building something far more complex and traditionally would do it as a jquery extension but I learned that those are terrible with garbage collection in the browser so I try to just build an object class(?, I'm not sure I use correct nomenclature) so I can destroy it better. Anyhow, I was really just wondering what the best way to do optional function parameters is. Forget that it's CSS it's just for illustration. Thank you.